# Update concat select for specific row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to update with 'model_name' with 'year_from' and 'year_to' data, but I've 6k models with random model_id, so I want to update model names that matches model_id. If I remove line 'where model_id = 2' it updates the whole table with min and max value. How can I modify this query?

```
UPDATE lc_vehicles2
SET model_name = concat(model_name, ' (', (
SELECT MIN(year_from) 
FROM (SELECT * FROM lc_vehicles2) AS VEHICLES
WHERE model_id = 2),'-', (
SELECT MAX(year_to) 
FROM (SELECT * FROM lc_vehicles2) AS VEHICLES
WHERE model_id = 2),')')
```

table structure:

```
brand_id | brand_name | model_id | model_name | year_from | year_to
502      | audi       | 2288     | A6         | 1999.06   | 2006.01
145      | volvo      | 2154     | S60        | 2006.06   | 2012.12
```

Comment: Using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php): `WHERE model_id = ?` or `WHERE model_id = :id`, (depending on what you prefer). Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Would you please share table structure in your question?

Comment: I mean I want it to upadate model_name accord to model_id. I have 6k models with random number for model_id with each having random number of dublicates. I wonder how can I solve this automatically without needing to manaully input model_id everytime.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE lc_vehicles2 VH
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(year_from) MIN_YEAR,model_id FROM lc_vehicles2 GROUP BY model_id
)MIN_TABLE ON MIN_TABLE.model_id=VH.model_id 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(year_to) MAX_YEAR,model_id FROM lc_vehicles2 GROUP BY model_id
)MAX_TABLE ON MAX_TABLE.model_id=VH.model_id
SET model_name = CONCAT(VH.model_name,'(',MIN_TABLE.MIN_YEAR,'-',MAX_TABLE.MAX_YEAR,')')
```

Try above query.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. Just edit SELECT MAX to choose from "year_to" just in case someone else finds this answer.